# How to save dataframe to Elasticsearch with mappings

Tags: scala, apache-spark, elasticsearch

I have following code to save dataframe to elastic search. It works well.

```
val conf = new SparkConf(true).set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", host)
    conf.set("spark.es.index.auto.create", "true")
    conf.set("spark.es.nodes", host)

 val features = sqlContext.read.parquet(input)

    features.write.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")
      .mode(SaveMode.Append)
      .option("es.resource","{ts}/log").save()
```

It autocreates index when it is not there. But when I try to query on some field. It shows following error

```
Set fielddata=true on [country] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory. Alternatively use a keyword field instead.
```

I am aware of the mappings to make text fields as keywords

```
{
  "your_field": {
    "type" "keyword",
    "index": true
  }
}
```

But I couldn't find how to use these mappings when creating index with this code

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, Elasticsearch for hadoop also creates a *.keyword* with keyword type already for you!

Try using `country.keyword`